# How to select last grand child?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Consider this **simplifcation**:

```
<div class="conversation">
    <div class="chat_message_container">
       <div class="chat_message bubble">1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="chat_message_container">
       <div class="chat_message bubble">2</div>
    </div>
   <div class="chat_message_container">
       <div class="chat_message bubble">3</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Now I select the last `.chat_message.bubble` in **each** `.conversation`, since I have multiple `.conversation`

So `$('.conversation .chat_message.bubble:last-child').each(..)` 
 Is not good since every bubble is a last child of `.chat_message_container`, it loops through all of the bubbles, how do I get only the last child of every `.conversation`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.map()`

Use

```
$('.conversation').map(function () {
    return $(this).find('.chat_message.bubble:last'); //Find last element
}).each(function(){
    alert($(this).text())
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/y8gRg/1/)

Comment: Using selectors was what I aimed for but since I mixed up the simplification and forgot to mentione the conversations are not in the same parent, I used this solution. Thanks Satpal!

Answer (score 1):

Apply `:last-child` to the `.chat_message_container` elements instead:

```
$(".conversation > .chat_message_container:last-child > .chat_message.bubble")
.each(function() {
    // ...
});
```

Comment: It should work with the markup in your question. Maybe that simplification is not actually representative of your actual markup?

Comment: Yes I'm afraid I was wrong, the `.conversations` does not rely in the same container

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
var num = $(".conversation .chat_message_container:last-child .chat_message").text();
alert(num);
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/L7Ps9/

Answer (score 0):

Select it like this:

```
$('.conversation .chat_message_container:last-child .chat_message.bubble:last-child')
```

Or for simplicity:

```
$('.conversation > div:last-child .chat_message.bubble:last-child')
```